# Delphi 10 Seattle strange Memo behaviour on Android 6

Tags: android, delphi, android-ndk, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

When I deploy my Firemonkey project on a Android 6 device the memo behaves strangely. 
When I press return to go to next line the cursor goes to the beginning of the Memo. Then if I type it goes back to the end and it will put the text in the correct position. When I exit the memo and want to put the cursor at the end of a line it won't let me. The cursor can only be positioned at the second to last character of a line for some reason. The same problem still exists in Delphi 10.1 Berlin. And it's only on Android 6 devices.

I am running SDK 23 with NDK r10e

I have already tried to change the SDK and NDK but it makes no differences.

Comment: Are you using a stylebook?

Comment: @nolaspeaker yes but I don't have a memo style in it. I use the default Memo style.

Comment: @nolaspeaker I've also removed the stylebook. The memo still act's the same strange way.

Comment: Maybe submit a bug report to Quality Portal.

Comment: @nolaspeaker Reported the issue: RSP-14985

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Android 6, but rather with the Google Keyboard.
By changing to a different keyboard like "Swift" the problem is solved!